# Find and change Default Start Firefox Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, command-line, firefox, default

this is my first post here, so apologize for any mistakes.
I am creating a script to customize an image of Ubuntu 22.04 and I also need to define the Firefox home page.
The first problem is that under the pref.js file I cannot find the "browser.startup.homepage" row until I open Firefox and set a random default page, so I'm not sure to can add the command "browser.startup.homepage" myself.
Second, after that the command should be

```
>sudo grep browser.startup.homepage ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/azk3h0gq.default/prefs.js
>user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.mysite.com");
```

But the terminal give me an error

```
>bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"browser.startup.homepage",'
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your prompt "`>$`" puzzles me. Please [edit] your question and show `ps -fp$PPID; id;env | grep -E  '^PS[1-4]='`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Here you are the answer of your command

UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
paralle+   84925    1992 10 09:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-
uid=1000(parallels) gid=1000(parallels) groups=1000(parallels),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.